# Outlook IMAP scopes giving an AUTHENTICATE failure with new MS Graph API

Tags: outlook, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, imap

I'm requesting the following scopes (URL encoded):

```
offline_access user.read https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send
```

The authorization process with OAuth 2.0 using the new Microsoft Graph API seems to work fine, but when using the access token to connect to IMAP over XOAuth2, I'm getting a `NO AUTHENTICATE`, which indicates the token is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is not an issue with the user but rather with Microsoft's Graph API. Although it is not documented, you are currently not allowed to request a token with a scope that falls under two tenants, or it will choose one and fail silently.

In this case, `User.Read` falls under Microsoft Graph tenancy. Technically speaking, if your user  is an organizational Outlook/Office365 user, they likely don't actually have Microsoft Graph installed and the correct scope would be `https://outlook.office.com/User.Read`. **However** the Outlook profile endpoint has been deprecated and would be unadvisable to use (you also have no way of knowing whether or not your user has MS Graph tenancy). It seems to resolve this, the `user.read` permission can be requested without specifying the Microsoft Graph URL.

This is essentially what you are doing above, but can be misleading as you are not actually requesting the general User.Read permission that can then be resolved to the Outlook tenant. What is actually happening is that User.Read permission is being mapped to some default tenant, and so your scopes actually contain multiple tenants (both the default tenant and Outlook).

Since this is not allowed, it fails silently and defaults to the default tenant. With most of their APIs this still works, but specifically with IMAP/SMTP you cannot request a larger scope/multi-tenant key or it will not validate over XOAuth2. You will note that the access tokens returned for IMAP/SMTP alone are always much smaller than the access tokens for other scopes.

To remedy this, you will need to request **two access tokens**. Firstly, you should use your authorization code to request a key within the following scope:

```
offline_access https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send
```

Following this, you need to request an access token for the profile. However, as of October 2020, you are no longer allowed to use a single authorization code for multiple access token grants. So you will need to login the user once more -- the canonical way of doing this is to simply navigate them back to the auth URL, leaving the `login_hint` field empty. This will vary depending on how you are constructing your URL, but here is an example in JS:

```js
url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?'
url += `client_id=${clientId}`
url += '&response_type=code'
url += '&redirect_uri=${redirectURI}'
url += '&response_mode=query'
url += '&login_hint='
url += '&scope=offline_access%20User.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2FIMAP.AccessAsUser.All%20https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2FSMTP.Send'
url += '&state=12345
```

**Note that your authorization code must request the full scope (including both `User.Read` and IMAP scopes like `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All`, for both access token requests.** Specifying a smaller scope will not guarantee that the profile you read will necessarily correspond to the Outlook account.

After receiving this second authorization code (it won't ask the user to login manually again, just load a bit and automatically resolve a second code) you can request a new access token with the following scope:

```
user.read
```

You can include any other Graph API scopes above, but specifying something under Outlook and especially under IMAP will mix up your scopes. The response scope will still contain EAS access and Outlook scopes, but with the addition of the `user.read` permission.

You should use this second token to access the profile and refresh it separately from the first token (which should only be used for IMAP/SMTP).